# Текстовые данные в односвязном списке без STL

Tags: c++, c, односвязный-список

Написал код, который создает односвязный список и выполняет стандартные операции с ним.
Но мой список может работать только с числами (int), теперь нужно что бы он мог работать с текстовыми данными. При том что по постановке задачи указано что "Стандартные классы и STL не использовать", то есть класс "string", если я правильно понимаю, использовать я не могу.
Пробовал использовать "char" вместо "int" и записывать через scanf("%s", &numb), но при выполнении функции push(добавление в конец), записывается в список совсем не то, что нужно. Так же, вместо "int" использовал массив сhar`ов (char data[255]), и для записи gets(), но тогда возникает больше количество ошибок, к примеру "|17|error: incompatible types in assignment of 'char' to 'char [255]'" и т.д.

Как мне следует изменить код что бы список поддерживал работу с текстовыми данными (желательно с строками и пробелами, к примеру с текстом "Привет мир!")?

Вот сам код (*Упростил до 2-х функций):

```
/**Работа с текстовыми данными*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
char data[255];
struct Node *next;
};

void append(struct Node** head_ref, char* new_data) ///добавление в 
конец
{

struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
struct Node *last = *head_ref;
new_node->data = new_data;
new_node->next = NULL;
if (*head_ref == NULL)
{
*head_ref = new_node;
return;
}
while (last->next != NULL)
last = last->next;
last->next = new_node;
return;
}

void printList(struct Node *node) ///печать списка
{
printf("--------СПИСОК--------\n\n");
while (node != NULL)
{
printf(" %s ", node->data);
node = node->next;
}
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUSSIAN");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);// установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в 
    поток ввода
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // установка кодовой страницы в поток 
    вывода
    struct Node* head = NULL;

    int keys;//переменная для switch
    while (1)
    {
    printf("1. Добавить в конец списка\n");
    printf("2. Печать списка\n");
    printf("0. Выход\n\n");
    printf("Ваш Выбор: ");
    scanf("%d", &keys);
    switch(keys){

    case 0:
    {
        system("CLS");
        break;
    }

    case 1:///Добавить звено в конец списка
    {
        system("CLS");

        printf("Введите Число: ");
        char new_numb[255];
        scanf("%s", &new_numb);//переменная в которую записывается 
        число для добавления в список
        char numb[256];
        strcpy(numb, new_numb);
        append(&head, numb);
        system("CLS");
        continue;
       }

    case 2:///Печать
    {
        system("CLS");
        printList(head);//печать
        printf("\n\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        system("CLS");
        continue;
    }

}
return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Вы, видимо, пытаетесь оставить для `char[255]` присваивание типа `new_node->data = new_data;`, но строки надо копировать (например, `strcpy`). А так это нормальное решение. Можно также выделять память динамически. Только вот копаться со всей вашей программой и всю ее переписывать вряд ли кому-то захочется... :(

Comment: Для упрощения кода вставки узла в список Вы можете реализовать функцию `insertAfter()` с проверками на начало и конец списка, а в функциях `push()` и `append()` использовать вызов `insertAfter()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harry, спасибо за ответ, функция копирования `strcpy` и запись очередного звена через `gets` помогли решить задачу. Поместил внутри append `strcpy(new_node->data, new_data);` и использовал вместо сравнения `if (temp != NULL && temp->data == key)` и `if(key_==ptr->data)` функцию сравнения строк `strcmp()`.

В результате код принял такой вид:

```
/**Работа с текстовыми данными.*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
char data[255];
struct Node *next;
};


void insertAfter(struct Node* prev_node, char* new_data) /// 
добавление после
{
if (prev_node == NULL)
{
printf("Предыдущий узел не может быть пустым.");
return;
}
struct Node* new_node =(struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(structNode));
strcpy(new_node->data, new_data);
new_node->next = prev_node->next;
prev_node->next = new_node;
}

void append(struct Node** head_ref, char* new_data) ///добавление 
 {
struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) 
malloc(sizeof(structNode));
struct Node *last = *head_ref; /* used in step 5*/
strcpy(new_node->data, new_data);
new_node->next = NULL;
if (*head_ref == NULL)
{
*head_ref = new_node;
return;
}
while (last->next != NULL)
    last = last->next;
last->next = new_node;
return;
 }

 void deleteNode(struct Node** head_ref, char* key) ///удаление 
 {
struct Node *temp = *head_ref, *prev;
if (temp != NULL && ((strcmp(temp->data, key))==0)) {
    *head_ref = temp->next; // Сменил голову
    free(temp); // освободить старую голову
    return;
}

while (temp != NULL && ((strcmp(temp->data, key))!=0)) {
    prev = temp;
    temp = temp->next;
}
if (temp == NULL)
    return;
prev->next = temp->next;
free(temp); // Свободная память
}


void Find(struct Node** head_ref, char* key_, char* numb_)
{

struct Node *ptr = *head_ref;
while(1)
{
    if((strcmp(key_, ptr->data))==0)
    {
    insertAfter(ptr, numb_);//вставить после
    printf("\n Элемент найден. Новое звено добавлено после %s.\n", ptr->data);
    break;
    }
    if(ptr->next == NULL)
    {
    printf("\n Элемент не найден\n");
    break;
    }
    ptr = ptr->next;}
    }


 void printList(struct Node *node) ///печать списка
 {
 printf("--------СПИСОК--------\n\n");
 while (node != NULL)
{
printf(" %s ", node->data);
node = node->next;
}
}

  int main()
 {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUSSIAN");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);// установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 
   в поток ввода
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // установка кодовой страницы в п 
  оток вывода
    /* Создаем новый пустой список */
    struct Node* head = NULL;

int keys;//переменная для switch
while (1)// или же while(true)
{
    printf("1. Добавить в конец списка\n");
    printf("2. Печать списка\n");
    printf("3. Удалить по значению\n");
    printf("4. Вставить после указанного\n");
    printf("0. Выход\n\n");
    printf("Ваш Выбор: ");
    scanf("%d", &keys);
    switch(keys){

    case 0:
    {
        system("CLS");
        break;
    }

    case 1:///Добавить звено в конец списка
    {
        system("CLS");

        printf("Введите Число: ");
        char numb[255];
        scanf("%s", &numb);//переменная в которую записывается число для добавления в список
        append(&head, numb); //добавление_в_конец
        system("CLS");
        continue;
    }



    case 2:///Печать
    {
        system("CLS");
        printList(head);//печать
        printf("\n\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        system("CLS");
        continue;
    }

    case 3:///Удалить по значению
    {
        system("CLS");
        printf("Введите Число: ");
        char numb[255];
        scanf("%s", &numb);
        deleteNode(&head, numb); //удалить
        system("PAUSE");
        system("CLS");
        continue;
    }

    case 4: /// Вставить после указаного
        {
        system("CLS");
        printf("Введите Число для поиска: ");
        char key[255];
        scanf("%s", &key);

        printf("Введите Число для вставки: ");
        char numb[255];
        scanf("%s", &numb);
        Find(&head, key, numb);//поиск+добавление
        system("PAUSE");
        system("CLS");
        continue;
        }


    default:
    {
        system("CLS");
        printf(" Некорректные данные,повторите попытку\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        system("CLS");
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
 }
 };
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).